# Error in Django: TemplateDoesNotExist at / materialize_css_forms/whole_uni_form.html

Tags: django, django-forms, materialize

I get this error message and can't find what I am missing.
I installed from PyPi pip install  django-materializecss-form
and added it to INSTALLED_APPS
I'm using django 3.0.8
I update my code regarding the first comment:

form.html

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load materializecss %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFghY">
</head>
<body style="padding: 20px;">
{{ form|materializecss }}
{% crispy form form.helper %}
</body>
</html>
```

forms.py

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Submit
from django import forms
from . models import Snippet

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField(label='E-Mail')
    category = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('question', 'Question'), ('other', 'Other')])
    subject = forms.CharField(required=False)
    body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'

class SnippetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('name', 'body')
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
    'crispy_forms',
    'materializecssform'
]

CRISPY_ALLOWED_TEMPLATE_PACKS = ('bootstrap', 'uni_form', 'bootstrap3', 'bootstrap4', 'materialize_css_forms', )
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'materialize_css_forms'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load **materializecss** to use it.

```
{% load materializecss %}
```

You need to add **crispy** to your form

```
{{ form|crispy}}
```

Comment: Should I write it right after the first one? Because this time it gives me Invalid filter: 'materialize'. I update my code please check it out

Comment: Still get the same error. It looks like it's from the filter

Comment: Now I'm getting again the first error from the title. I really can't find the problem...

Comment: @developer Can you try {{form|crispy}} in body and remove helper and materialize line from body tag?

Comment: This works perfectly! Many thanks!!! It looks like I don't need to load crispy at all at this html file. Thanks again)))

Comment: I have edited answer. Please accept it so that it would be helpful for future users